# Adhoc provision profile

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am new to iPhone development. I have this problem :

I am working with another developer and he has generated an ADhoc_APP.mobileprovision to distribute the application to the testers. He can generate the .ipa with his machine by doing the build/archive/share...

He sent me the adhoc_app.mobileprovision by email to install it in my xcode. The problem is I have tried to integrate it to my xcode and I can't.

When I do build/archive on my computer I get the error : `Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Distribution' doesn't match any identity in any profile.`

Please, can someone tell me how to integrate the adhoc provision profile on my machine ( and if there are other things to do) so I can generate the .ipa.

thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adhoc provisioning profiles are usually not for development, but for testers not using XCode. They just install the provisioning, and then, the app.

If you have a developer profile with all valid certificates (team & developper) and the source code, then choose iPhone Developer in your project settings.

If you want to sign the application with the adhoc provisioning profile, then you have to be in the same "development team" that the developer who generated the adhoc profile

PS : take a look to all other topics on the same subject...

Answer (score 1):

You also need the certificate in .p12 format. Ask the another dev. to export this distribution certificate from keychain in .p12 format and install it on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

When adding provisioning profiles to an environment the easiest way I have found to achieve this without stress is to drag the profile (or certificate) onto the XCode icon in the dock.

You can check that the certificate has successfully been added to the development environment by opening the Organiser window and choose the first item in the tab list which is Devices.

The Organiser will show you all the profiles that are installed in your environment. It will also highlight in yellow (or red) any issues there might be with any profiles. You can delete old or unwanted profiles here too.

For certificates - Double click the certificate you have downloaded and it should get added to your keychain. You will probably have to give the administrator password to allow this. Open up the keychain to see what certificates are installed in your environment.

It's a really good idea to get your head around the profiles and certificates that are installed and delete old and unwanted items early on to save confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I know this. When you log in "super admin" of provision profile site, you send a key of your computer to subscribe and it create a .p12 file. All other people who will use the "archive" (or build for distribution, i think) will need this file. There are no other way to get it if you lost.

If you really lost, will need to revoke the actual file, subscribe the computer (or other) another time and send this file to everyone. I think you will need actualize the provision profile again.