# which provisioning profile is required so that any user has access to install app on their iphone?

Tags: iphone

I want to post my iphone app on my website and users will be downloading it from my site.
which provisioning profile is required so that any user has access to install app on their iphone?(I cant go for appstore for distribution ).

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can look at Enterprise license. More details: http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done only through an enterprise distribution program. You can create a **"In-house" distribution profile**, that can be installed on any iOS device. However it is supposed to be used by employees of an enterprise only. You can't post it on any public website, available to download for anyone.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a Distribution Provisioning profile.

Answer (score 0):

You can create AdHoc certificate for an Application and have your clients/users install them on their device.

P.S. :It has device limit of 100.

For more info visit link :

[Adhoc provision profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978457/adhoc-provision-profile)

[What is an Ad Hoc certificate for iOS test app distribution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955605/what-is-an-adhoc-certificate)

Another option is [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/) to distribute your application among your clients.